# Read HBase in Scala - it.nerdammer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I would like to read HBase data in a Spark stream code for looking up and further enhancement of streaming data. I am using `spark-hbase-connector_2.10-1.0.3.jar`.

In my code the following line is successful

```
val docRdd = 
  sc.hbaseTable[(Option[String], Option[String])]("hbase_customer_profile")
    .select("id","gender").inColumnFamily("data")
```

`docRdd.count` returns the right count.

`docRdd` is of type

> HBaseReaderBuilder(org.apache.spark.SparkContext@3a49e5,hbase_customer_profile,Some(data),WrappedArray(id,
>   gender),None,None,List())

How can I read all the rows in `id, gender` columns please. Also how can I convert `docRdd` into a data frame so that SparkSQL can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all rows from the `RDD` using

```
docRdd.collect().foreach(println)
```

---

To convert the `RDD` to a `DataFrame` you could define a case class:

```
case class Customer(rowKey: String, id: Option[String], gender: Option[String])
```

I have added the row key to the case class; that's not strictly necessary, so if you don't need it, you can omit it.

Then `map` over the `RDD`:

```
// Row key, id, gender
type Record = (String, Option[String], Option[String])

val rdd = 
  sc.hbaseTable[Record]("customers")
    .select("id","gender")
    .inColumnFamily("data")
    .map(r => Customer(r._1, r._2, r._3))
```

and then - based on the case class - convert the `RDD` to a `DataFrame`

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = rdd.toDF()
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

The output from `spark-shell` looks like this:

```
scala> df.show()
+---------+----+------+
|   rowKey|  id|gender|
+---------+----+------+
|customer1|   1|  null|
|customer2|null|     f|
|customer3|   3|     m|
+---------+----+------+

scala> df.printSchema()
root 
 |-- rowKey: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- id: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks @Beryllium. I shall try this. I want to use the RDD in SparkStream. I hope it is serializable as well. Thanks once again for the help

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?